# What does [[ -z "path" ]] mean in bash

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I found this line in a bash script:

```
if [[ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]; then
    source ./env/bin/activate
fi
```

I was wondering what it meant?

(I hope that's not a duplicate question, but it's very hard to google bash commands as they're single letters)

Comment: I means "is null". IOW, "if this no virtualenv defined, then ..."

Comment: Tip for googling:  put -z in quotes, otherwise the `-` negates the search

Comment: FYI: `-z` isn't a single letter bash command. it is an argument to the `[[` shell built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man test` ([link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test))

It checks whether the string is zero length. In bash there is no distinction between null and empty string, so also returns true if the string has not been set.

Comment: also documented in `man bash` and `man test`

Comment: The ABS is a rather poor choice of references -- infrequently updated, and without care to showcasing good practices. Consider the man page, the bash-hackers wiki, or the wooledge wiki instead.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression are good places to start.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - in this case it's the ideal choice of references as it's the first relevant google result (making it the quickest way to find the correct answer). However, I agree in principle that there are much better canonical references for this information, and will now edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: If people stopped linking to it, it wouldn't *be* the top google result.